# Irregular 3D object with flat edges for CNC mill

Tags: obj

I am fighting with this and it seems that my Blender skill is still not enough to master this problem. I am in need of an 3D object that has flat surfaces but which are irregular in shape (I did my best to try to draw it so please see picture attached).

Can anyone advise or maybe provide a sample file on how can I make an object and then change its dimensions (width, height...) and also change the pattern of the edges? Also this needs later to be extracted as obj in order to make toolpath.

As I need a lot of these any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This may help.  https://youtu.be/2bf42SQ8TC4 but it sounds like you just need to add and move edges around. Also https://youtu.be/d-zpR1E84nQ

Comment: @RickT, I had to model a vase similar to this for interior visualisation once. If you start moving stuff around manually, it starts to get really hard to keep the faces planar so I think it's not the best approach. I think Booleans are the way to go here. It would also be be non-destructive kind of workflow for easier editing.

Comment: True, it's hard to do without exact dimension.  It almost reminds me of 3d vornoi puzzle pieces  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=3d+vornoi+puzzle&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a cube, duplicate it (Ctrl+D), move the duplicate to new collection (M) and set its viewport display to wire so you can see through:

[image]

Then you can use Boolean modifier set to collection mode:

[image]

This way you can keep duplicating the cubes and placing them around at different locations and in different orientations to cut volume away until you are happy with the result.